# Bash command history stops working after starting new tmux session

Tags: bash, centos, tmux

My bash command history stops working after starting a new `tmux` session. No previous commands when typing up, down, reverse search, no output from running `history`.

I've confirmed that this happens regardless of the `.tmux.conf` file being used. The real kicker is that this condition persists beyond `tmux` ... that is, if I ssh to the server without `tmux` the bash command history still doesn't work. If I move my `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` files (using the system default) and try again, still no history.

I've verified that all the permissions are correct on the history file, my user is both the owner and the group, and even tried setting perms to 777 just to test. For each test I re-executed bash (ie didn't use a subshell).

For some context, this happened after my all my files were copied over to a new server.

Another clue: In the original shell where I started `tmux` for the first time, if I exit `tmux`, the command history still works. It is only new shell sessions that are affected.

Some more info:

```
CentOS release 6.7 (Final)
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
tmux 1.6 (other server was 1.4)

set | grep HIST and hist
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
HISTFILE=/home/my_username/.bash_history
HISTFILESIZE=1000
HISTSIZE=1000
SHELLOPTS=braceexpand:emacs:hashall:histexpand:history:interactive-comments:monitor
BASHOPTS=checkwinsize:cmdhist:expand_aliases:extquote:force_fignore:hostcomplete:interactive_comments:login_shell:progcomp:promptvars:sourcepath

shopt | grep hist
cmdhist         on
histappend      off
histreedit      off
histverify      off
lithist         off
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you have the same `$BASHOPTS`, `$SHELLOPTS` and `$-` in the working and non-working shells? Does `!!` work? Do other interactive shell features (e.g. completion) work?

Comment: @Gilles yes I verified they are the same. `$-` outputs `himBH`. `!!`, `!$`, etc do not work, (eg `-bash: !!: event not found`). but `$?` and `$-`, etc work.

Comment: I think this is just the way `bash` works. Each history is session specific, as I understand this. If you are inclined, you could try `zsh` which has specific capabilities of sharing history between sessions.